# C++ make variable constant once set

Tags: c++

for example if I have

```
std::string test;
```

I want to be make test constant as soon as I initialize it.

```
test = "hi";
test = "test"; //this shouldn't work since I already initialized test to hi above
```

is this possible?

Comment: It's already been initialized before you assign "hi".

Comment: `std::string const test = "hi";`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare it `const` and initialize it to the value you are interested in:

```
const std::string s = "hi";
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should understand the difference between assignment and initialization in C and C++.  `std::string test;` calls the default string constructor, so `test = "hi";` would also fail.

It is not possible at the language level to cause a compile error on only the *second* time something is reassigned - and why should it?  One this would be confusing and two the # of assignments that happen will be determined at runtime in the general case, not compile time.

Proper use here is to use `const` and "assign" - actually, initializing, not assigning at all - in the same statement in which it is declared, i.e. `const string str = "hi";`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a const reference once you have your assigned string:

```
std::string s = "hi";
const std::string & const_s = s;
const_s = "test" // compile-time error
```

But I agree that it sounds like you just want to initialize a const string with a value.